# Will category discounts double if items are in multiple categories?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

If I set up a catalogue discount for 40% off the women's category and 40% off the sale category, will items that live in both the women's and the sale category end up at 80% off? What is the best way to do this without having to rearrange all our items?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [Catalog Rules](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog-create.html) then the answer is the customer gets a 40% discount on those product, not 80%. Take one of **catalog price rule** based on **Priority** field.